# What's the proper way of binding SelectedDates property in wpf?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

A calendar project which has multiple selected dates as my wish and these dates will be generated in C#.
So what will be the binding process in SelectedDates property in wpf?
And what will be the C# code which can return a Date to the binding target?
Here are some of my xaml codes

```
<Calendar x:Name="_calendar"
                  Style="{DynamicResource CalendarStyle1}"
                  CalendarDayButtonStyle="{DynamicResource CalendarDayButtonStyle1}"
                  CalendarButtonStyle="{DynamicResource CalendarButtonStyle1}"
                  IsManipulationEnabled="True"
                  SelectionMode="MultipleRange"
                  SelectedDate="{Binding }">
        </Calendar>
```

Comment: @zaggler not really ... There is no answer how to bind to `SelectedDates`

Comment: @Selvin there is an answer, `Wouldn't you have a DateTime property in your VM that is bound to the calendar and that raises PropertyChanged?` what isn't clear about this approach? If not understanding, I would recommend reading up on mvvm to get an understanding about how binding and or `INotifyProperty` changed works.

Comment: @zaggler Everything .. `SelectedDates` is not `DateTime` ... and it's read only property

Comment: `SelectedDates` is read only, you need to target `SelectedDate`. You'll have to have something that will hold more than one date, for example a `ObservableCollection<DateTime>` for multiple dates.

Comment: Target `SelectedDate` to bind range ... interesting

Comment: @Shakil you wana bind single date or range ?

Comment: @Selvin range/multiple range

Answer (score 0):

You can not do binding to SelectedDates property of Calendar, because it is read only property, but you may dynamically add values to it, following example shows how add values to Calendar and getting selected dates:

XAML:

```
            <StackPanel Margin="10">
            <Calendar Name="_calendar" SelectionMode="MultipleRange"
                      />
            <Label>Selected dates:</Label>
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=_calendar, Path=SelectedDates}" MinHeight="150" />
            </StackPanel>
```

Source:

```
            _calendar.SelectedDates.Add(DateTime.Today.AddDays(-5));
            _calendar.SelectedDates.Add(DateTime.Today.AddDays(-2));
            _calendar.SelectedDates.Add(DateTime.Today.AddDays(5));
            _calendar.SelectedDates.Add(DateTime.Today.AddDays(15));
```

Result:

[image]